# How can I autosize cloumns by character number in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, ag-grid

I have a page writed with Vue and ag-grid. I want to set columns' width as responsible. The incoming data come in the same format every time.

[image: slice]

For example I want to give a width that 3 characters will fit to first column because the incoming data always contains 3 characters. In the same way I want to give 1 character width to the last column.

```
api.autoSizeColumns()
```

Doesn't solve my problem because it gives so much space to columns. For example the last column in the picture.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `maxWidth` for the first and last columns. In this case autosizing will effect as you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [Grid System](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/).
I think the `colspan/rowspan` will solve your problem.